# Django cache doesn't invalidate on change

Tags: django, caching, django-rest-framework

A cached page should be invalidated when something changes at the underlying resource. Django implements "site-wide" caching and I used [this guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache-1) to setup my caching infrastructure (locally to test for now).

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    }
}
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = "default"
CACHE_TTL = 60 * 60 * 1
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = CACHE_TTL
```

When I run my tests now, it works too well, as all tests fail, which change information in the database. Do I have to manually add a flag for cache invalidation? Should this even work (or are my settings wrong)? I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61277009/django-rest-cache-invalidation), but in my case I don't use any decorators, but the side wide caching. Nevertheless I tested using the `vary_on_headers('Authorisation',)` which didn't change the test results.

Comment: had the same problem, never figured out how to fix that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this discussion in the Django forums](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/invalidating-cache-doesnt-happen-automatically/13780/5), it seems like the automatic site caching isn't actually designed for this. It is more or less designed for caching a page until it expires, not until it is invalidated, because there is no way to invalidate a page manually.

There is always the way of using the caching [backend manually though](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/cache/#basic-usage).